# How to obtain a filled contourplot from my data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a filled contourplot that shows the variation of fluxes with vertical levels for different wavenumbers. The x-axis is the wavenumber. Y-axis represents the vertical levels.

I have 70 different files, each representing a particular level. In each file, I have two columns that are the wavenumber and the flux. For a corresponding wavenumber and vertical level, the flux needs to be plotted. I have attached two pictures of how it should look like and what I am getting. I don't understand what seems to be wrong when reading the files. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

filelist=[]

for i in range(1,71):
    filelist.append("kespec_TL%s.asc" %i)

for i in filelist:
    data=np.loadtxt(i)
    x=data[:,0] # Wavenumber

z=np.empty((71,283))
for i in enumerate(filelist):
    z[i,:]=np.loadtxt(i)[:,1] # Flux array

f=np.loadtxt("atm_hyb_sz_70.txt")
y=f[:,1] #vertical levels
##
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
#
plt.contourf(X,Y,z,20,cmap='RdGy')
plt.show()
```

Desired result:

[image: Expected]

What I'm getting:

[image: result]

Edit: The working code

```
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import sys

filelist=[]

for i in range(1,71):
    filelist.append("kespec_TL%s.asc" %i)



g=np.loadtxt("kespec_TL1.asc")
x=g[:,0]
f=np.loadtxt("atm_hyb_sz_70.txt")
y=f[:,1]

z=np.zeros((71,283))
for i,gname in enumerate(filelist):
    z[i,:]=np.loadtxt(gname)[:,1]

#sys.exit()
plt.semilogx(x)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
levels=[0,0.5,2,7,10,20,70]
plt.contourf(X,Y,z,levels,cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('Spectra.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post one of the files? Or at least part of one so we can see the format?

Comment: @user12760571 Something that's strange is that `x` is constantly completely overwritten in this loop: `for i in filelist: data=...; x=data[:,0]`. Maybe `x` should be filled in similar to `z`? Apart from that, `x` and `z` are nowhere declared.

Comment: The other plot is semilogx.  Did you try `plt.xscale('log')`?   However, you are correct that you are not filling your x matrix correctly.  Initialize to zero(283) and then fill as you read the files in.

Comment: @JohanC the values of x are constant- meaning that x is constantly overwritten by the same values(1-300) for very loop. But you are correct though, I filled the x matrix as I did the y matrix and I loaded the text data wrongly for z which seemed to be the problem.

Comment: So your question can be marked as solved?

Comment: Yes, it can be marked as solved